# SSRS only showing blank reports

Tags: reporting-services

I've been trying to get SSRS working but I only get blank reports (using the sample reports from codeplex).

Logs have this error
ui!ReportManager_0-1!1430!04/26/2011-20:10:27:: Unhandled exception: System.Web.HttpException: Path '/Reports_ANTHONYWS/ScriptResource.axd' was not found.
   at System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your settings in Reporting Services Configuration Manager all look OK? I ask because it looks like you've changed the default "Reports" virtual directory to "Reports_ANTHONYWS", wonder if this is affecting anything.